# Confused Javascript post

Tags: javascript, html, razor, form-submit

I've the below data in html.

```
@Html.BeginForm("LoginDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post){

<body onload="makeCalls()" style="background-image: url('../../ImageIcons/FaceLoginBG.jpg'); background-size: cover; visibility:hidden">


    <div class="captureAndCompareWindowForLogin" style="display: block; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;float: none;">
        <div class="centerTitle">
            <h3 style="color:white">Welcome</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="errText" id="errText" value="errText" visibility:hidden">Invalid Username and Password</div>
        <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
            @Html.Label("Username") <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid"/><br /><br />
            @Html.Label("Password") <input type="password" id="pswrd" name="pswrd"/><br /><br />
            <input type="button" id="btnLogin" onclick="check()" value="Login" class="btn-block">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check() {
            /* the following code checkes if user is given access */
            var userNameFromForm = document.getElementById("userid").value;
            var passwordFromForm = document.getElementById("pswrd").value;
            var lower = userNameFromForm.toLowerCase();

            if (userNameFromForm === "") {
                alert("please enter your username");
            }
            if (passwordFromForm === "") {
                alert("please enter your password");
            }
                //Display error message, reset the form and select the userid textbox
            else {
                console.log(document.getElementById("loginForm"));
                document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();

            }
        }
    </script>


</body>
}
```

when I click the button, without blank `username` and `password`, it is giving me the appropriate alert message, but, filled username and password and hit submit is giving me the below error.

```
LoginHome:142 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null.
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, problem is that you wrapping form inside another form. Please use it like that:

```
<body onload="makeCalls()" style="background-image: url('../../ImageIcons/FaceLoginBG.jpg'); background-size: cover; visibility:hidden">


    <div class="captureAndCompareWindowForLogin" style="display: block; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;float: none;">
        <div class="centerTitle">
            <h3 style="color:white">Welcome</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="errText" id="errText" value="errText" visibility:hidden">Invalid Username and Password</div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
        {
        @Html.Label("Username") <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid" /><br /><br />
        @Html.Label("Password") <input type="password" id="pswrd" name="pswrd" /><br /><br />
        <input type="button" id="btnLogin" onclick="check()" value="Login" class="btn-block">
        }


    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check() {
            /* the following code checkes if user is given access */
            var userNameFromForm = document.getElementById("userid").value;
            var passwordFromForm = document.getElementById("pswrd").value;
            var lower = userNameFromForm.toLowerCase();

            if (userNameFromForm === "") {
                alert("please enter your username");
            }
            if (passwordFromForm === "") {
                alert("please enter your password");
            }
                //Display error message, reset the form and select the userid textbox
            else {
                console.log(document.getElementById("loginForm"));
                document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();

            }
        }
    </script>


</body>
```

Your code will submit form to `Home/LoginDetails` url. Your method in HomeController should be like this:

```
public ActionResult LoginDetails(string userid, string pswrd) 
{
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the following:

`@Html.BeginForm("LoginDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post)`

Or
You can use following instead, after deleting the 'LoginDetails' forms tag.

`document.getElementById("LoginDetails").submit();`